# Get location on Receiving push

Tags: ios, core-location

Is there an alternative, where a device gathers location and sends it to the server, when a request is being made from the server?

Or is there any such API in MDM?

Any idea how Find My iPhone works?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nithin

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no MDM API for location information.

You would need to create an application and deploy this with MDM, and have the application send the information back to your server, in order to get the behaviour required.